# How to do conditional text formatting in TiddlyWiki list items?

Tags: conditional-formatting, tiddlywiki5

I in my wiki I have a Tiddler that is a dragable list of items, a timeline of events in a story. I use a template Tiddler for the items to format them depending on the tags of the list items so I can quickly identify how important they are. Currently I use macros and the set-widget to apply the formatting and that's okay if you ave just a few but it quickly gets complicated if there are more than two. Currently my template looks like this

```
\define strike(text:"")
~~$text$~~
\end

\define grey(text:"")
@@.empty
$text$
@@
\end

\define normal(text:"")
$text$
\end


<$set name="macro" filter="[<currentTiddler>tag[spoiler]]" value="spoiler-inline" emptyValue="normal">
<$set name="arrow" filter="[<currentTiddler>tag[event]]" value="→ " emptyValue="">
<$set name="color" filter="[<currentTiddler>has[text]then[normal]else[grey]]">
<$set name="skipped" filter="[<currentTiddler>tag[skip]]" value="strike" emptyValue="normal">
<<arrow>> <$macrocall $name=<<macro>> text="""<$macrocall $name=<<color>> text='<$macrocall $name=<<skipped>> text="<$link/>"/>'/>""" />
</$set>
</$set>
</$set>
</$set>
```

I new to TiddlyWiki and that's all I could come up with. The problem I have is that I don't know how I can have more than three formattings (escaping the nested macrocall widgets) that can be applied simultaneously.